# Storyboard ChildViewController instance

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a `viewcontroller` (`ChildViewController`) that extends another view controller (`ParentViewController`).
In projects that I didn't use storyboards I used to instance the `ChildViewControllers` by calling `[super initWithNibName:bundle:]`, but in projects with storyboards I have to call `[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier]`.
My problem is if I do that on the `childviewcontroller` I get a `parentviewcontroller` instance instead of a `childviewcontroller` instance.

Any Ideas how to that?

Comment: If the class of the view controller (in IB) with the identifier you pass in instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, is ChildViewController, then you should get a controller of that class. Are you sure you set the class correctly?

Comment: On child init Im calling parent controller from IB, I don't want to have multiple designs for them

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment. If you want a child, you have to init a child not a parent. If it's the views you're worried about, you can do a copy and paste of the parent controller, then change the class of the copy to ChildViewController.

Comment: Yes I can have multiple views in the IB, but I dont want it, because if I need to change one I have to change them all. I want to initialize my child with the layout of parent view controller. I use to do that when I was not using storyboards with [super initWithNibName:bundle:]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. If you're using a storyboard, you want to show all your controllers -- if several of these are ChildViewControllers, then I think you have 2 choices. You can copy and paste like I said, or you can leave the views blank and load the view from the parent's xib file in initWithCoder. But if you do the latter, you won't be able to hook up any segues (since you won't have any buttons or table views showing). Even if you had 10 ChildViewControllers, it wouldn't take a minute to paste a new view into them if you changed the parent view.